# Ember 2.6 button action binding not triggering template update

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I come to stackoverflow feeling a little defeated. I have searched far and wide for an answer to this, but I have an action from a button that appears to not be triggering a proper update of a template, and I don't know why.

I'm working directly off of the [ember docs for route actions](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/actions/) and have tried more combinations of things, like inline vs component, than I would like to admin. Alas I am stumped, so I am coming here for help. Here is my code:

```js
// app/admin/users/edit/route.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  isEditingPassword: false,
  actions: {
    toggleBody() {
      this.toggleProperty('isShowingBody');
    },
    editPassword() {
      this.toggleProperty('isEditingPassword')
      console.log('(after toggle) isEditingPassword', this.get('isEditingPassword'))
    },
    saveUser(model) {
      model.save().then(()=> {
        console.log('we saved!')
        this.transitionTo('admin.users');
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- app/admin/users/edit/template.hbs -->
{{outlet}}
<button {{action "editPassword" on="click"}} class='button is-danger'>{{if isEditingPassword "Edit user" "Edit Password"}}</button>
{{input class="input" type="text" name='title' value=isEditingPassword placeholder="True"}}


{{#admin-user isEditingPassword=isEditingPassword model=model saveUser='saveUser'}}{{/admin-user}}
```

The component itself that this is calling is rather simple, and looks like this:

```js
// app/components/admin-user/component.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    saveUser(model) {
      console.log('save the user!', model)
      this.sendAction('saveUser', model);
    },
    cancel() {
      this.sendAction('cancel')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- app/components/admin-user/template.hbs -->
{{yield}}
{{#unless isEditingPassword}}
  {{#admin-user-form model=model
    saveUser='saveUser'}}
  {{/admin-user-form}}
{{else}}
  {{#admin-user-password-form model=model
    saveUser='saveUser'}}
  {{/admin-user-password-form}}
{{/unless}}
```

Lower components are also there, but not relevant to this question.

The kicker with this issue, is that as you can see from the code above, I also have an **ember input helper** that is bound to the same property. Updating this text input works, and causes the conditional in the lower component to fire as expected and the button text to update. However with the button, neither the lower component conditional, nor the inline conditional in the button function at all, and stay at the default state.

I have exhaustively tried searching for answers to this, but am coming up blank. I have **also tried** utilizing **computed properties** both on the route and lower component to *no avail*. I am sure it is a simple solution, but I am completely missing it.

So my question is simple, why would the action from the button not trigger the conditional to update in the template? The `console.log` event *does* fire.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties on `Route` are not available in your template.  The context for your template is the `Controller` for the route, which (big source of unexpected bugs) proxies to the model returned by your Route's model hook.

In order to use a route action in this way, you would need to update the param on the controller, or update a property on the model.

Alternatively, implement the Controller.  Top level route controllers for handling actions and exposing computed properties are still perfectly ok, despite what you may have heard about far future deprecations.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up shifting the logic down further into a component because of this. i didn't know that the properties on routes were not available on templates. Shifting those down solved this.